# How to draw a bitmap as a button?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-button

I m trying to draw a button which consist of a bitmap,like

```
b[j] = (Button) sm.findViewById(R.drawable.picture);
```

but i m not able to display this picture using the `draw(Canvas canvas)` method.

is there a way how i can display the button like a bitmap as in

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,..,..,null);
```

i actually dont want to display the button from an xml or inside the `onCreate()` method.

is there a way i can display it from anywhere else????

Thank you!!!!

i will post my program here please help!!!

have created four classes...

enter code here

```
**class 1:-**


package game.pack;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Sushitap extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(new SushiMain(this));


   }
}


**class 2:-**

 package game.pack;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.Button;


public class SushiMain extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    Canvas canvas;
    Tower s;
    SushiThread st;
    int height;
    int width;

    public SushiMain(Context context) {


        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        DisplayMetrics met = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        height=met.heightPixels;
        width= met.widthPixels;

        int x=width;

                s = new Tower(context,this,x,260);

        st = new SushiThread(getHolder(), this);
        setFocusable(true);

    }




    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder sh, int format, int height,
            int width) {
        getResources();
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder sh) {

        st.setRunning(true);
        st.start();

    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

            boolean retry = true;
          while (retry) {
           try {
            st.join();
            retry = false;
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {

           }
          }

         }

        public void render(Canvas canvas) {

                            s.onDraw(canvas);
}

}

**class 3:-**

package game.pack;

import android.graphics.*;
import android.view.*;

public class SushiThread extends Thread{

    private SurfaceHolder sh;
    private SushiMain sm;
    Tower t;
    private boolean running;

    public SushiThread(SurfaceHolder sh,SushiMain sm)
    {
        super();

        this.sh=sh;
        this.sm=sm;


    }



    public void run()
    {
        Canvas canvas;

        while(running)
        {

            canvas=null;

            try{

                canvas=this.sh.lockCanvas();

                synchronized (sh) {


                    this.sm.render(canvas);
                }


            }
            finally{

                if(canvas!=null){

                    sh.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

                }

            }




        }


    }

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running=running;

    }


**class 4**

package game.pack;

import java.util.Random;



import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Tower extends View

{
    int x,y;
    ImageButton sushiArray; 
    Canvas canvas; 



    public Tower(Context c,SushiMain mainObj, int x, int y) {

        super(c);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;


    }   


        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


            sushiArray.draw(canvas);



    }


}




please let me know how to implement my imageButton.,,thank you!!!
```

Comment: Not sure if this will fit your requirements, but have you tried using an ImageView and using onClick to initiate the action when the user presses the image?

Comment: actually i want it to be like this link..
http://kahdev.wordpress.com/2008/09/13/making-a-custom-android-button-using-a-custom-view/
could you just guide me with that..thank you!!!

Comment: That articlw is too old. Android has a `ImageButton` control for this purpose. use it.

Comment: so does that work like a normal bitmap which would give me clickable fucntions too???

Answer (score 1):

Use [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) to display an image on a button instead of text.

Answer (score 1):

(1)You can use the ImageButton to accomplish you moto , like this:

```
   <ImageButton android:id="@+id/theImageButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_your_image" />
```

here "ic_your_image" is the image which you want to show as a button.

(2) Or, you can simply use an image view and make it clickable by setting onClickListener on it.

(3) You can do it programmatically as well :

```
            View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.your_main_xml);

            ImageButton newButton=new ImageButton(this);
            newButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getApplication().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_image)); 
            newButton.setId(5);
            noLisnText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            noLisnText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(newButton);
```

To set the bitmap in the imageview(I am not sure about it, you have to test it):

```
       View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.your_main_xml);
            ImageView newImage=new ImageView(this);
            newImage.setId(5);
            newImage.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(newImage);
            newImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: I dont want to create the button through xml.I want it to created from my program. Can i call the draw function inside the onDraw method of the imagebutton??

Comment: you can set the place of this button in the screen using setLayoutParams() and setGravity() etc. methods.

Comment: The code which I have given can be accessed from anywhere. Just create a method which has this code and pass the context of that activity and Content view i.e. layout for that activity as arguments in this function. And use this context argument in place of getApplication() method and "this" keyword. May be that will help you.

Comment: but i need to create an array of imageButton and they keeping on changing positions in the screen.can u please suggest how i can draw the imagebutton inside the onDraw method in my program????

Comment: Well I have no idea about that. sorry for that.

Comment: hey can you help me with the imageView please...
i m trying to make an imageView for the bitmap...so how can do it in the above program???

Comment: So you want to dynamically generate an imageview and set bitmap into it?

Comment: yes i want to make it dynamically and also move d imageview in the screen!!!!
please can you also tell me how to draw it.beacuse i m having problems drawing it to.
what should i be drawing in the onDraw() method the bitmap or the imageView....m only able to draw the bitmap not the imageView.

Comment: yes but will i get the onclickListener for the bitmap???
can you send me a small code as how i m doin in my class 4 please...
thank you!!!

Comment: Well, I am affraid to say I don't have much idea about it.